# Sonarqube API Call wrong Response

Tags: api, http, sonarqube, httpresponse, devops

when closing a branch in a continous integration environment my scripts are also supposed to delete associated sonarqube projects.

To achieve this I am using the sonarqube API as described in the WebAPI documentation. I am adressing the endpoint `api/projects/delete` with corresponding project-key. If the deletion is successful the http request is answered with `204 - No content` if the project was not created in sonarqube or was deleted already I get `404 - Not found` which makes sense and can be handled programmatically.

Since a few weeks the responses are inconsistent and it can happen that I get the response `200 - Ok` for a ressource that is not in Sonarqube. The results are different per day, time or project I try to delete.

Does anyone has an idea where this could come from? The Sonarqube API documentation lacks some detail regarding to the expected status codes.

It is obvious that I could handle this in my code as well. But since the solution worked like this for ages I am wondering where this did come from.

I am running Sonarqube 6.7.5.38563.

Thanks in advance.

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After alot of manual API calls with Postman I found the problem.

Deletion is taking to long so that SonarQube is displaying the "Loading..." pages which give back a response code 200.

Strange behaviour because this can't be fixed by increasing the timeouts on the calling side. Is there any chance to adjust the value in Sonarqube when a Loading Page should be displayed?